# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Gatling - when running Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

My Gating script is erroring with the below message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testSimulation
```

But I didn't do anything off and just followed the documentation. I get this error only on Jenkins, not directly on my machine. So I am thinking something very obvious is wrong but I can't seem to figure it out.

My script looks like this:

```
package computerdatabase
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class testSimulation extends Simulation {.....
```

This is the snippet above.

Like I said, this works locally but not on the same versioned Gatling I use via Jenkins.

Any ideas would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct and indeed, you don't have a class whose Fully Qualified Class Name, is `testSimulation`.

The correct Fully Qualified Class Name of your simulation is `computerdatabase.testSimulation`, you're missing the package.

Comment: Thanks mate! That did it